# -[Lifestyle Mismatch] ApplicationSignInManager (Web Request) depends on IAuthenticationManager (Transient)

Tags: c#, autenticação, simple-injector

Estou recebendo um erro na inicialização do `simpleinjector` que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. O erro aparece quando ele tenta executar a linha:

```
container.Verify();
```

Segue erro:

> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] ApplicationSignInManager (Web Request) depends on IAuthenticationManager (Transient).

Classe SimpleInjectorInitializer:

```
using CCValemixEF.Infra.IoC;
using CCValemixEF.UI.Web.App_Start;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebActivatorEx;

[assembly: PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SimpleInjectorInitializer), "Initialize")]

namespace CCValemixEF.UI.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

            // Chamada dos módulos do Simple Injector
            InitializeContainer(container);

            // Necessário para registrar o ambiente do Owin que é dependência do Identity
            // Feito fora da camada de IoC para não levar o System.Web para fora
            container.Register(() =>
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying)
                {
                    return new OwinContext().Authentication;
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

            });

            container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            container.Verify(); << Aqui acontece o erro.

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
        }

        private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
        {
            BootStrapper.RegisterServices(container);
        }
    }
}
```

Classe BootStrapper:

```
using CCValemixEF.Application.AppInterface; using CCValemixEF.Application.AppServices; using CCValemixEF.Domain.Interfaces.Contracts; using CCValemixEF.Domain.Interfaces.Services; using CCValemixEF.Domain.Services; using CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Context; using CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Identity.Configuration; using CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Identity.Model; using CCValemixEF.Infra.Data.Repository; using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework; using Microsoft.Owin; using Microsoft.Owin.Security; using SimpleInjector; using SimpleInjector.Advanced; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Net; using System.Web;

namespace CCValemixEF.Infra.IoC {
    public class BootStrapper
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
        {
            #region Defaults
            container.Register<ApplicationDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

            container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()), Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>(() => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(), Lifestyle.Scoped);

            container.Register<ApplicationRoleManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<ApplicationSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            #endregion

            #region Aplicação
            container.Register(typeof(IAppServiceBase<>), typeof(AppServiceBase<>));
            container.Register<IFilialAppService, FilialAppService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            #endregion

            #region Dominio
            container.Register(typeof(IServiceBase<>), typeof(ServiceBase<>));
            container.Register<IFilialService, FilialService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            #endregion

            #region Repositories
            container.Register(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>), typeof(RepositoryBasse<>));
            container.Register<IFilialRepository, FilialRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            #endregion
        }
    } }
```

Alguém poderia me falar onde estou errando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que o erro aconteça quando você registra os seus `owin authentications`, utilizando o método `Register` sem passar como parametro seu lifestyle, ele assume como padrão o `Transient`, nesta linha:

```
container.Register(() =>
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying)
                {
                    return new OwinContext().Authentication;
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

            });
```

Como nesta linha aqui:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
```

você esta registrando o seu `container` com um lifestyle `WebRequest`, que tem uma vida maior que a dos seus Owin Authentications, esta ocorrendo esse erro, de acordo com a documentação [Diagnostic Warning - Lifestyle Mismatches](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LifestyleMismatches.html). Neste link te da mais informações sobre o problema e a lista de lifestyles ordenadas por seu tempo de vida.

Recomendo que no método `Register` coloque um lifestyle mais longo, por exemplo, `LifeStyle.Scoped`:

```
container.Register(() =>
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && container.IsVerifying)
                {
                    return new OwinContext().Authentication;
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

            }, LifeStyle.Scoped);
```

https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_Register__1_3.htm

Aqui há mais alguns exemplos caso queira mais informações, além dos links da documentação postados anteriormente:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826996/lifestyle-mismatch-web-request-depends-on-transient-in-simple-injector

Comment: dae Gabriel, era isso mesmo... o tempo de vida.... muito obrigado pela ajuda...salvou!!!